# Removing an item from array: Wrong item being removed

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have a page of posts with a list of media attachments. I want the user to be able to manually delete an attachment(s) when he clicks the "delete" link. This event is working, however, **the problem is that the actual item being deleted is not the one that is being clicked!** What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code and a live demo here: [[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/delete-attachments-nolodash-jqql4)] (*click POSTS-->choose a post ID to view post details --> click EDIT post*)

> EditPost.vue `<template>` section:

```
...snip..
    <ul>
      <li>Media Attachments
        <template>
          <ul v-if="attachmentsFileNames && attachmentsFileNames.length">
            <li v-for="(mediaAttachment, index) in attachmentsFileNames" :key="index">
              <a href="#">{{ mediaAttachment }}</a>&nbsp;
              <button @click.prevent="deleteMediaAttachment(mediaAttachment, index)">Delete me!</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p v-else>No Media Attachments</p>
        </template>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

> EditPost.vue `<script>`:

```
...snip..
data() {
    return {
      post: {},
      editPostFormIsVis: false,
      attachmentsArray: attachments
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getPost();
  },
  methods: {
    getPost() {
      axios
        .get(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + this.$route.params.id
        )
        .then(resp => {
          this.post = resp.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
    editPost() {
      this.editPostFormIsVis = true;
    },
deleteMediaAttachment: function(item, index) {
      if (this.attachmentsArray.attachments[index] === item) {
        // The template passes index as the second parameter to avoid indexOf,
        // it will be better for the performance especially for one large array
        // (because indexOf actually loop the array to do the match)
        this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        let found = this.attachmentsArray.attachments.indexOf(item);
        this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(found, 1);
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    emailAttachmentsFileNames() {
      if (this.attachmentsArray.emailAttachments) {
        const emailAttachmentsFileNameArray = this.attachmentsArray.emailAttachments.map(
          item => {
            const tokens = item.split("/");
            return tokens[tokens.length - 1];
          }
        );
        return emailAttachmentsFileNameArray;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    attachmentsFileNames() {
      if (this.attachmentsArray.attachments) {
        const attachmentsFileNameArray = this.attachmentsArray.attachments.map(
          item => {
            const tokens = item.split("/");
            return tokens[tokens.length - 1];
          }
        );
        return attachmentsFileNameArray;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
...snip...
```

Comment: Is the deletion off-by-one?  Yea, this looks like off-by-one error, check your indexing.

Comment: `attachmentsFileNames` and `attachmentsArray` does not hold the same items so `this.attachmentsArray.attachments.indexOf(item);` returns -1 since item comes from attachmentsFileNames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you send in the item from the `attachmentsFileNames` and try to match it to an item in the original `attachments` array. The first contains the filename while the second contains the full path so they won't match. For example:

```
console.log(item);                                     // star_wars_luke.jpeg
console.log(this.attachmentsArray.attachments[index]); // attachments/2019/201900002020/star_wars_luke.jpeg
```

That's why `this.attachmentsArray.attachments[index] === item` is `false`, then `this.attachmentsArray.attachments.indexOf(item)` returns `-1` and consequently, `this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(-1, 1)` always removes the last item in the array.

Since you parsed the `attachmentsFileNames` array yourself from `this.attachmentsArray.attachments`, you can rely on the `index` corresponding correctly so those checks aren't even needed. Just remove them and run `this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(index, 1)` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your deleteMediaAttachment function to

```
deleteMediaAttachment: function(item, index) {
  this.attachmentsArray.attachments.splice(index, 1);
},
```